# xmldoc <see> with cref that refers to a class under a separate csproj

Tags: xmldocument, docfx

We have an SDK project that includes a test engine. These live under two different csproj's. So we have `SDK.csproj` and `TestEngine.csproj` where `SDK.csproj` is a `ProjectReference`.

I have a DocFx project set up that builds metadata for these two separately, with docfx.json metadata that looks like this:

```
{
  "src": [
  {
    "src": "../../sdk",
    "files": ["csharp/SDK/**/*.cs"]
  }],
  "dest": "reference/SDK"
},
{
  "src": [
  {
    "src": "../../sdk",
    "files": ["csharp/TestEngine/**/*.cs"]
  }],
  "dest": "reference/TestEngine"
}
```

This way I can set up TOC's to put these documentation trees under separate tabs.

However, I cannot use a `cref` in `TestEngine` xml docs that refers to a class from `SDK`. I get an error like this from DocFX build: 
`Warning:[MetadataCommand.ExtractMetadata]Invalid cref value "!:SDK.SDKClass" found in triple-slash-comments for TestEngineClass, ignored.`

I can imagine why this fails - DocFX is generating the metadata for `TestEngine` alone so it doesn't know about the `SDK` classes or how to link to them. Is there a way I can change the configuration so that I can keep these two projects separate (under separate TOC's) in the final website but still link from `TestEngine` to `SDK` classes?

Comment: Oh! I've found that `@` references work on the pages generated from the triple slash comments. So `@SDK.SDKClass` works in place of `<see cref="SDK.SDKClass">` in my example. For some reason I thought this only worked on the Markdown articles. (This may be DocFx specific, and I'm curious if there is another solution, so I won't add this as an answer to this question just yet)

Answer (score 1):

I realized that using `@` and/or `xref` tags as described in the [DocFx documentation](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/tutorial/links_and_cross_references.html) do resolve to links properly in the generated web pages. So that gets me a lot of what I want. However, it's not a complete solution as other generated references do not resolve to links. For example, if a `TestEngine` method has a parameter of type `SDK.SDKClass`, the generated docs won't make a link for `SDKClass` where it appears on the parameter documentation. So I'm still wondering if there is another solution.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: nope. It's a pretty small problem at least.